# Accessing the value that's not part of the form

Tags: html, forms, form-submit

In my html I have a combo box which list all the available `usertypes` and then the input varies by what the user selects on the combo box so you can see that I have my onchange.

But my question is how would I be able to access the value of the selected combo box? Is it possible to get its selected value even it is not a part of the form? I've already tried to have only one form that is

```
<form action="" name="form1" method="post">
<select id="usertype" name="usertype" class="dropdown-select" onfocus="getPrevious()" onchange="set()"  >
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Chairperson</option>
        <option value="2">Dean</option>
        <option value="3">Faculty</option>
        <option value="4">Staff</option>
        <option value="6">Admin</option>
      </select>



<div id="formpage_Chairperson" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
<input type="text" value="" name="A" />
<input type="text" value="" name="B" />
<input type="text" value="" name="C" />
<input type="text" value="" name="D" />
<input type="text" value="" name="E" />
<input type="text" value="" name="F" />
<input type="Submit" value="Submit Form" name="submitForm" />
</div>


<div id="formpage_Chairperson" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
<input type="text" value="" name="A" />
<input type="text" value="" name="B" />
<input type="text" value="" name="C" />
<input type="Submit" value="Submit Form" name="submitForm" />
</div>

</form>
```

But when I clicked the Submit Form nothing happens. You can see that I'm choosing only what to display because different `usertypes` (e.g. Chairperson, Dean, etc) have also different inputs. So I make different forms for each particular `usertypes`. But then it throws an error ' Undefined index: usertype ' and I know that is because it's not part of the form.
 So can you give me some advice on how will I be able to come up with this properly? Thank you.

**Here is my html code:**

```
<select id="usertype" name="usertype" class="dropdown-select" onfocus="getPrevious()" onchange="set()"  >
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Chairperson</option>
        <option value="2">Dean</option>
        <option value="3">Faculty</option>
        <option value="4">Staff</option>
        <option value="6">Admin</option>
      </select>



<form action="" name="form1" method="post">
<div id="formpage_Chairperson" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
<input type="text" value="" name="A" />
<input type="text" value="" name="B" />
<input type="text" value="" name="C" />
<input type="text" value="" name="D" />
<input type="text" value="" name="E" />
<input type="text" value="" name="F" />
<input type="Submit" value="Submit Form" name="submitForm" />
</div>
</form>

<form action="" name="form1" method="post">
<div id="formpage_Dean" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
<input type="text" value="" name="A" />
<input type="text" value="" name="B" />
<input type="text" value="" name="C" />
<input type="Submit" value="Submit Form" name="submitForm" />
</div>
</form>
```

This is the Javascript for handling the onchange event of the combo box:

```
var prev = ""

    function pagechange(topage) {
    var page;
    if (prev.length > 0) {
        page = document.getElementById('formpage_' + prev);
        if (page)
            page.style.visibility='hidden';
            page.style.display = 'none';
    }

    page = document.getElementById('formpage_' + topage);
    if (!page)
        return false;

    page.style.visibility='visible';
    page.style.display = 'block';
    prev = topage;
    return true;
    }

    function set(){
    var e = document.getElementById("usertype");
    var selection = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    pagechange(selection);
    }
```

Comment: Not possible without using some javascript to grab it on form submit.  By why not make it part of the form?

Comment: @cale_b I can't do it Sir because I have a javascript that handles the combo box. So that when you make it part of those forms the javascript will not function properly. I hope you can get me.

Comment: @Harvey Javascript would be the way to go.  OnSelectedChange or something like grab the value and then you can stuff that value into a hidden input variable or something.

Comment: What's the JS that handles the combo box look like? Maybe it's a simple issue as to why it doesn't work inside the form.

Comment: @fletch I've edited my question and include the Javascript code.

Comment: did the solution I proposed work out for you?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you wanted to "access" it. I'm assuming you mean with the rest of the form data, so you could do something like the following:

```
function pagechange(topage) {
    var page;
    if (prev.length > 0) {
        page = document.getElementById('formpage_' + prev);
        if (page) {
            page.style.visibility='hidden';
            page.style.display = 'none';
        }

        page = document.getElementById('formpage_' + topage);

        // create hidden input field and append to form
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        input.setAttribute("name", "page");
        input.setAttribute("value", topage);
        page.appendChild(input);
        // end of changes

        if (!page)
            return false;

        page.style.visibility='visible';
        page.style.display = 'block';
        prev = topage;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also, you were missing a closing bracket on your `if (prev.length > 0)`, so I closed it right before the `return true;`. You may need to adjust depending on your logic.

Hope this gets you close.